# Why should event listeners be removed in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As far as I am concerned the event listeners as such

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const height = window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
      setWindowSize(window.innerHeight);
    });

    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", height);
  }, []);
```

will stop working upon refreshing the page and it should continue working throughout the time the website is in view.

What is the need of cleaning up then?

Comment: `window.addEventListener()` always returns `undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the event listener will make the component more robust, make the app quicker, and reduce memory leaks.

If you only do

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
      setWindowSize(window.innerHeight);
    });
  }, []);
```

Then, if the current component gets unmounted, but the user doesn't navigate away from the page, the listener will persist, despite the fact that the component the listener is useful for doesn't exist anymore. It probably doesn't matter much for a `resize` listener, nor for computations as simple as these, but:

- If the computations were more expensive, that'd be wasted CPU time on a component that doesn't exist in the DOM; better to remove the need for the calculations entirely
- If the added listener happens to fire extremely rapidly (like `scroll`), removing the listener could help performance, especially if there are multiple components like these

If this component will always exist when your app is running, there's no need for cleanup, strictly speaking - but returning a cleanup function will be more elegant and will make refactoring easier, should you ever decide to change around the structure such that the component *might* not always be rendered.

Another issue: you're not removing the event listener properly. Use this instead:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const resizeHandler = () => setWindowSize(window.innerHeight);
  window.addEventListener("resize", resizeHandler);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", resizeHandler);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote it wrong, it should be:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const height = () => setWindowSize(window.innerHeight);
  window.addEventListener("resize", height);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", height);
},[]);
```

What if your component unmounts and then remounts without removing the event listener? You'll be calling `setWindowSize` on an unmounted component, which react tells you is a no-op, and could indicate a memory leak, but in the future, maybe it throws an error?

Always clean up after yourself. It's a good habit.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning up a single eventListener might not make that much sense in a small project; but in general that listener will be stored in some place (e.g. heap). Imagine if every component register an event and doesn't clean them up, after a while we will have a bunch a pointless event listeners that are no longer attached to the original components and remained in the memory, but will be executed anyway;  which will waste resources (i.e. cpu, memory) and make the app slower, laggy, and less efficient.